# Tag merge request: [php-library] -> [php]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

I don't think [php-library](/questions/tagged/php-library) is a good tag.  It is ambiguous, provides no information that doesn't have to be clarified in the question and can be misleading.  Are they talking about the SPL, their own library, a third-party library or an extension?  Either way, it is something that needs to be clarified with another tag or content in the question.

There are currently only 16~ questions with this tag.  I am willing to go through and manually retag these to [php](/questions/tagged/php), I am simply not sure if it would be appropriate to retag that many questions without community feedback.

Comment: 16 is under the threshold where nobody'll notice.  If you don't get to'em by tomorrow morning, I'll probably nuke them all myself.

Comment: Sounds like a meta-php tag to me

Comment: Looks like someone got to it before me.  Darn!

Comment: I agree with the nuking, but not the tag synonym request.  The two tags do not appear to mean the same thing.